# Docker Mongodb: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.96.2:27017

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose locally, my app works fine. but when I push it on my web server, I get the following error :

```
connection error : MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server 
[mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 
192.168.96.2:27017]
```

I don't get what's going on.

Here is my docker file :

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["node", "server"]
```

My docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'

services: 
  app:
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
    container_name: data-foot-api-container
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports: 
      - '80:3001'
  mongo: 
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/data/db
volumes:
  data-football:
```

If someone have an idea about how it could come from, I would really appreciate it

Comment: could you share the output of this command `docker ps `?

Comment: by the way, remove useless CMD from dockerfile `CMD ["mongod", "service", "start"]` and the `link` section from docker-compose file

Comment: It looks like your app ports are reversed for app. I assume you want your host port 3001 to point to port 80 in your app container? it should 3001:80.

Comment: @andolsi zied , thanks for your reply, here is the result :
    e022cee1e87f        data-foot-api_app   "node server"            47 seconds ago      
    Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:80->3001/tcp       data-foot-api-container
    f4f98357ef43        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 seconds ago      
    Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb

Comment: @pwaterz I want to hit port 80 when the app is live, I tried it locally and it works as expected : when I hit port 80, it then point on port 3001 of my nodejs app

Comment: could you post the output of this command : `docker exec data-foot-api_app curl mongo:27017`

Comment: @andolsi zied , I get the following message : It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
 (i change from data-foot-api_app to data-foot-api-container, as data-foot-api_app was refering to the image, thus I couldn't get response with the command you provided)

Comment: @Andolsi zied, here is the resultof the "docker ps" command : 
5fc401575f82        data-foot-api_app   "node server"            2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp     data-foot-api-container
3dfc9b32cc88        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb

Comment: This feels like the problem that all of the containers start at once but aren’t necessarily immediately ready, and your Node client tries to contact the Mongo server before it’s actually running.  If you put an artificial sleep at the start of your script, does it work?  (There are better actual answers but that’s an easy hacky check.)

Comment: @David Maze is it a screep to implement in Docker file ? or docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: you can add a script to force node to wait for mongo to be up. see this link https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys for helping me.

It was indeed due to the fact that Node container was ready and running BEFORE mongo container.
Thus, Node was trying to reach mongo, but mongo wasn't up yet.

I found a way to force docker to wait for mongo to be ready before building node container here : https://dev.to/hugodias/wait-for-mongodb-to-start-on-docker-3h8b

There is probably other ways to do it, if someone knows another way or a better way, please comment.